# Why won't my discord bot work?

Tags: node.js, bots, discord

Recently, I have been trying to make a discord bot. All has gone well, until I run the start.bat file.
As soon as I run it, I get this:

```
    client.on('ready', () => {
                    ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

Here's the sample code I'm using to get the bot off the ground:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.login('MzEzNzc1NzUwOTQxNTA3NTg0.C_-ilQ.vJyMW_Q2PjLLntwgifRRCnjPw88')
client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.username}!`);
});
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'ping') {
    msg.reply('Pong!');
  }
});

client.login('token');
```

And My start.bat file:

```
@echo off
node bot.js
PAUSE
```

Finally, here's the version information:

```
2 info using npm@2.7.4
3 info using node@v0.12.2
```

Any clue what this means, and how I can fix it?

Comment: Please post the [complete, relevant code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and your version of Node.js; the error message you've posted does indicate that you have a syntax error, but it's not enough to actually determine what the problem may be.

Comment: That's a syntax error, meaning it doesn't know how to parse your code. What version of Node are you using? does it work using regular anonymous functions instead of the shorthand?

Answer (score 0):

The arrow function syntax (`() => { }`) is relatively new, and has only been supported since Node 4.0. Since you're using an outdated version of Node, I'd highly recommend that you upgrade it to the newest version, as it's no longer officially supported, and a lot of the code you'll find online takes advantage of features that were introduced in newer versions of Node.

You can download the newest version from the [official Node.js site](https://nodejs.org/en/).

Comment: No matter what I do, I cannot seem to be able to update node.js. I even did a manual install and it still is on 0.12.

Comment: @CMWAidanx Then don't use arrow functions, try replacing any `() => {}` to `function() {}`

Answer (score 0):

I hope you figured this out already, but you're missing a semicolon on the line before you declare the event.